# SharePoint Online - React Modern Script Editor - Install Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

Having an issue with the react modern script editor (sp-dev-fx-webparts), on the npm install.

Lots of warnings, and one key error.

I've tried a lot of different things I found on the internet and looking for suggestions:

```
gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:468:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

NPM Version: 6.14.4
Node Version: 14.1.0

Answer (score 1):

"The current supported LTS version of NodeJS for the SharePoint Framework is Node.js v8.x and Node.js v10.x. Notice that 9.x, 11.x or 12.x versions are currently not supported with SharePoint Framework development. Above links are pointing to 10.20.1 version."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Microsoft official site and download the latest verson of Node js .. try to install it again . I faced the same issue and i re install everything and download the latest file and installed. Now all are fine .